# Parameters used in GridSearchCV Slow Down in skLearn Tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

**I'm not sure why `grid.fit(X,y)` is correct, rather than `grid.fit(X_2d, y_2d)`**

In this tutorial on [RBF SVM Parameters](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html), we are using `GridSearchCV` to find the optimum hyperparameters for an SVM.

They have the following code:

```
# Dataset for decision function visualization: we only keep the first 
two
# features in X and sub-sample the dataset to keep only 2 classes and
# make it a binary classification problem.

X_2d = X[:, :2]
X_2d = X_2d[y > 0]
y_2d = y[y > 0]
y_2d -= 1
```

...

```
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range, C=C_range)

# GridSearchCV will search the parameter space for the best parameters to use, minimizing the score function
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv)

# ==================== CODE I'M INTERESTED IN  ==================>
# ===== SWITCH `grid.fit(X,y)` with grid.fit(X_2d, y_2d) ========>
grid.fit(X, y)
# ==================== ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  =============>

print("The best parameters are %s with a score of %0.2f"
      % (grid.best_params_, grid.best_score_))
```

where `X_2d` and `y_2d` are a subset of `X` and `y`.

---

**Just some information to show what `X` and `y` are:**

```
print(X.shape)    #(150,4)
print(y.shape)    #(150,)
print(X_2d.shape) #(100,2)
print(y_2d.shape) #(100,)
print(type(X))    #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(y))    #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(X_2d)) #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(y_2d)) #<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Why does changing the code above to `grid.fit(X_2d, y_2d)` not work? I'm not sure if it's taking a very long time, OR that it's incorrect. My Jupyter Notebook is just sitting, whereas `grid.fit(X, y)` only takes seconds.

My original thought was that we would want to fit to the actual data set we're running on which are `X_2d` and `y_2d`, rather than `X` and `y`

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't sure whether the code works or not, you could turn on gridsearch output:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=param_grid, cv=cv, verbose=2)
```

I just run the script in your link - it worked fine for me. Are you sure you didn't change something while working on the code?